# Filtro por rango de fechas

Tags: c#

Tengo un proyecto en capaz y estoy filtrando los datos de un DataGridView 
por rango de dos fechas FechaInicial y FechaFinal estos dos lo voy a filtrar con 
DateTimePiker1  y DateTimePiker2

**Este es el procedimiento almacenado en sql server**

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[BuscarProyectoF]
@fechaini datetime,
@fechafinal datetime
as
SELECT T0.CodProyect AS Codigo, T0.NomProyect AS NombreProyecto,T3.NomComplet AS Completado ,T1.NomEstad AS Estado, T2.NomResp AS Responsable, T0.FCreacion AS FCreacion ,
T0.FInicio AS FInicio,T0.FFin AS FFin,T0.FEntrega AS FEntrega, T0.Notas
FROM tblproyect T0
                  INNER JOIN tblestado T1 ON T1.CodEstad = T0.CodEstad
                  INNER JOIN tblrespon T2 ON T2.CodResp = T0.CodResp
                  INNER JOIN  tblcomplet T3 ON T3.CodComplet = T0.CodComplet
                  where T0.FInicio between @fechaini and @fechafinal
```

**Acá llamo el procedimiento con los dos parámetros** "Esto esta en la capa de DataAccess"

```
 public DataTable BuscarProyectoF(DateTime fechaini, DateTime fechafinal)
        {
            using (var connection = GetConnection())
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "BuscarProyectoF";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaini", fechaini);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechafinal", fechafinal);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Luego en la capa presentación llamo el procedimiento de esta manera**

```
 private void BuscarProyectoF(DateTime fechaini, DateTime fechafinal)
        {
            UserDao objtarea = new UserDao();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = objtarea.BuscarProyectoF(fechaini, fechafinal);
        }
```

luego en el botón donde va buscar

```
 private void BtnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BuscarProyectoF(DateFechaInicial);

        }
```

si pueden ver  lo que falta es llamar los DateTimePiker en lo parametros en c#

es decir

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaini", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePiker1.Text;
```

pero no puedo hacer esto por que mi proyecto es por capas  los DateTimePiker están en la capa presentación mas no hago la conexión en el mismo formulario osea que en DataAccess no se va a poder poner, en que parte de las capa llamo los date DateTimePiker

Comment: En el evento click del boton buscar solo debes hacer: `BuscarProyectoF(DateFechaInicial.Value, DateFechaFinal.Value)`

Comment: Perfecto Gracias Amigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero que hace ruido es a que llamas "capa de presentacion" porque cuando la mencionas defines un metodo

```
private void BuscarProyectoF(DateTime fechaini, DateTime fechafinal)
```

y tambien esta el evento

```
private void BtnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

pero ambos son capa de presentacion, por lo tanto si los unes

```
private void BtnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserDao objtarea = new UserDao();
    var proyectos = objtarea.BuscarProyectoF(DateTimePiker1.Value, DateTimePiker2.Value);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = proyectos ;
}
```

podrias tomar el valor de los `DateTimePiker` y pasarlos a la capa de datos